# JQuery 3.5.0 producing odd output using html

Tags: jquery

I am aware that jQuery 3.5.0 has a security fix in it as documented here

https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/04/jquery-35-xss-vulnerability-fix/

however I was still surprised by this case. Is it right?

Here's my example. There are links to 2 jQuery libraries, the old and the new. You can comment one and use the other

https://jsbin.com/baretotepo/edit?html,js,output

The code is minimal and self explanatory, a stripped down example from a real case

It tries to put some html on the page, but it has an error as shown here

```
<div>
  <i class="Tag" />   <--- error here
  <i class="A"></i>
</div> 
<div>
  <i class="B" />
</div>
<div>
   <i></i>
</div>
```

In jQuery 3.4.1 this would produce

```
<div><i class="Tag"></i><i class="A"></i></div> <div><i class="B"></i></div><div><i></i></div>
```

In jQuery 3.5.0 this produces

```
<div><i class="Tag"><i class="A"></i></i></div><i class="Tag"> <div><i class="B"></i></div><div><i class="B"><i></i></i></div></i>
```

It's duplicated the 'i' tag with the class 'B'

It's not a valid input so I will accept an answer of "that's just the way it works"

This is in Chrome

Comment: clearly its struggling with self closing tags...it wil probably work if you dont use self closing tags

Comment: Yes, what was surprising was the degree to which it mangles the output now when it was arguably right previously

Comment: I'd suggest raising that as a bug with the jQuery devs. While the `<i />` syntax should never occur this is clearly a regression as 3.4.1 handled it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I asked the JQuery github forum, this was the response:

This specific duplicating tag behavior is surprising but it's a result of two things:

1. jQuery 3.5.0+ doesn't try to fix content for you & the HTML parser treats `<i />` as just `<i>` - only the opening tag.
2. As shown in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#misnested-tags:-b-i-/b-/i, `<i>` is a [formatting element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#formatting) and the parsing algorithm mandates that if you close an outer tag without closing an inner formatting element, it gets closed & immediately re-opened after the outer tag closing tag.

   This shows one of the reasons why `<i>` is not just a shorter version of `<span>` if you reset its default CSS, different semantics of this tag actually matter; I'd advise against using `<i>` elements for anything that's not just formatting-related.

Comment: This applies to all tags not considered "void", i.e. tags which can ever have content.  Like `<div>`, for instance, or `<span>`.